# Which chemical reactions don't involve bond breaking?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, bond

I recently came across a question in which an option is 'Breaking a chemical bond is the first step in any chemical reaction', which lead me to think of reactions which do not involve bond breaking. The only reaction I can think of is dimer formation, but a Google search reveals no more. Surely this cannot be the only example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reaction of a Lewis acid with a Lewis base results only in bond formation. Your question gets at the essence of chemistry, though. A chemical reaction is the rearrangement of electrons between atoms. So generally, most reactions will involve breaking bonds. Even for monomers (e.g. alkenes) to polymerize, $\pi$-bonds within the monomers have to be broken to form $\sigma$-bonds in the polymer. You seldom have one without the other.

Comment: Electron transfer is such an example; $\ce{D + A \to D^+ = A^-}$.

Answer (score 3):

Precipitation reactions?  If you will grant me that an aqueous ion is free.  (But maybe you don't and consider the solvated ion bonded to nearby water.)

Answer (score -1):

[Per a source](https://www.scotmas.com/chlorine-dioxide/why-is-clo2-different-to-chlorine.aspx?locale=en), to quote:

> Like ozone, the predominant oxidation reaction mechanism for chlorine dioxide proceeds through a process known as free radical electrophilic (i.e. electron-attracting) abstraction rather than by oxidative substitution or addition (as in chlorinating agents such as chlorine or hypochlorite).

So, the reaction:

$\ce{.ClO2 + e- -> ClO2-}$